# Media query not working for IsotopeJS grid items

Tags: html, css

I have this grid-container which have several cards. To sort and filter, I'm using IsotopeJS. But before I implement that feature, I wanted to make my grid items somewhat presentable.

To do that, I have been trying to have 3 items on each row on screen sizes greater than 992px, 2 items for 992px to 768px and 1 item below that. For that I used `width: 33.33%`, `width: 50%` and `width: 100%` to `.grid-item` respectively. I also want a margin of 10px on each item.

But right now the grid is showing 2 items for screen sizes greater than 992px and 1 item below that.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Here's the snippet of the code:

```js
$('.items-container').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item'
});
```

```css
section{
    min-height: 400px;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 50px 0;
}

.items-container{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.grid-item{
    width: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.grid-image {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ef969a;
    height: 200px;
}


.grid-image img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}




@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .grid-item{
        width: 50% !important;
    }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 568px) {
    .grid-item{
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<section>
    <div class="items-container">
    
        <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="grid-image">
                image
            </div>

            <div class="grid-caption">
                <p>caption</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      
        <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="grid-image">
                image
            </div>

            <div class="grid-caption">
                <p>caption</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      
        <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="grid-image">
                image
            </div>

            <div class="grid-caption">
                <p>caption</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      
        <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="grid-image">
                image
            </div>

            <div class="grid-caption">
                <p>caption</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="grid-image">
                image
            </div>

            <div class="grid-caption">
                <p>caption</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      
        <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="grid-image">
                image
            </div>

            <div class="grid-caption">
                <p>caption</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      
    </div>
</section>
```

How can I fix this? Would be a big help if someone points me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest wrapping your grid-item content in a div and use padding on it.

https://jsfiddle.net/qw3m2jvd/ (updated)

Edit: To take the full width of the container, I have given negative margin to .items-container and overflow:hidden to section. Make sure the negative margin is same as padding applied to .grid-item-wrap.

And to make it look like items have space between them I have added/updated some css, like background color of .grid-item is black and for p tag in .grid-caption it is white with padding instead of margin.

```js
$('.items-container').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item'
});
```

````css
```
section{
min-height: 400px;
background-color: black;
padding: 50px 0;
overflow:hidden;
}

.items-container{
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
margin:0 -10px;
}


.grid-item{
width: 33.33%;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #000;
}
.grid-item-wrap{
padding:10px;
}

.grid-image {
width: 100%;
background-color: #ef969a;
height: 200px;
}


.grid-image img{
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

.grid-caption p{
  margin:0;
  padding:1em 0;
  background-color:#fff;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
.grid-item{
    width: 50% !important;
}
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 568px) {
.grid-item{
    width: 100% !important;
}
}
```
````

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<section>
<div class="items-container">

    <div class="grid-item">
        <div class="grid-item-wrap"><!--Wrap div-->
            <div class="grid-image">
                image
            </div>

            <div class="grid-caption">
                <p>caption</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <div class="grid-item-wrap">
            <div class="grid-image">
                image
            </div>

            <div class="grid-caption">
                <p>caption</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <div class="grid-item-wrap">
            <div class="grid-image">
                image
            </div>

            <div class="grid-caption">
                <p>caption</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <div class="grid-item-wrap">
            <div class="grid-image">
                image
            </div>

            <div class="grid-caption">
                <p>caption</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <div class="grid-item-wrap">
            <div class="grid-image">
                image
            </div>

            <div class="grid-caption">
                <p>caption</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <div class="grid-item-wrap">
            <div class="grid-image">
                image
            </div>

            <div class="grid-caption">
                <p>caption</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  
</div>
</section>
```

Note: If you haven't already, you should check out this link about 'gutter' to add space between grid items if above css hacks don't work for you - https://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html#gutter

Comment: the padding makes the image have edges which I don't want. I want to take the full width of the container. Moreover, because of padding, the items doesn't have spaces between them.

Comment: Hey, I have updated my answer. I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

If you see the rendered code after Isotope adds the effect, it also adds an absolute positioning to each `grid-item`. The `top` and `left` value takes over your intended positoning. I have a CSS Grid solution for you and let me overriding the absolute positioning with relative so that the items aren't out of flow.

[`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) on the `.items-container` takes care of the card items to be displayed on the various media query rules.

You may also need to add a height for the container as mentioned here - https://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes.html#horizontal-layouts

```js
$('.items-container').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item'
});
```

```css
section {
  min-height: 400px;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.items-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; /* 3 columns layout */
  grid-gap: 20px;
  height: 810px !important;
}

.grid-item {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative !important; /* Don't take this out of flow */
  left: auto !important; /* Override IsotopeJS's left */
  top: auto !important; /* Override IsotopeJS's top */
}

.grid-image {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ef969a;
  height: 200px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.grid-caption {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.grid-image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .items-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; /* Two columns layout */
    height: 900px !important;
  }
  .grid-item {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 568px) {
  .items-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr; /* One Column layout */
    height: 1800px !!important;
  }
  .grid-item {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<section>
  <div class="items-container">

    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-image">
        image
      </div>

      <div class="grid-caption">
        <p>caption</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-image">
        image
      </div>

      <div class="grid-caption">
        <p>caption</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-image">
        image
      </div>

      <div class="grid-caption">
        <p>caption</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-image">
        image
      </div>

      <div class="grid-caption">
        <p>caption</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-image">
        image
      </div>

      <div class="grid-caption">
        <p>caption</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-image">
        image
      </div>

      <div class="grid-caption">
        <p>caption</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Couple of issues with this approach. It has a padding throughout the whole body. The default isotope effect has gone. And .grid-caption container gets huge at screens bigger than 992

Comment: Custom CSS can be hacky but not a standard solution. What is the problem if you go ahead with their layout methods? https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/zFart

Comment: I wanted to but I was unable to make the grid responsive.